# tweepy.cursor is not callablepylint(not-callable)

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to print followers from twitter using the
'''
for follower in tweepy.cursor(api.followers).items():
print(follower.name)
'''
but am getting this type of error ****tweepy.cursor is not callablepylint(not-callable)***
av tried using from '''tweepy import tweepy''' but it too is getting more errors >like module cannot be imported from class tweepy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Cursor (instead of cursor):

```
import tweepy

api = tweepy.API(auth)
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
  print(follower.name)
```